# Can I create a class using an eval function?

Tags: python

I am trying to make an automatic class maker so that somebody that doesn't know how to use python can create a class without effort. Here is a shortened version of my code that returns the same error:

```
class myclass:
    pass
eval("c=myclass")
```

Of course in this case I could just use normal python without the eval, but since I have user input, it won't work.

Comment: `eval` must be an expression.  You probably want `exec`

Comment: I recommend you to use any alternative ways.